# Recyclerview inside NestedScrollView closes the bottomsheet

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have this page with a map, and if the user clicks a button, a bottomsheet is expanded. In this bottomsheet, there are 2 tabs, on which there is a list. If I scroll the list with a movement from down to up it works fine. The opposite movement from up to down, instead of scrolling the list back, it makes me close the bottomsheet.

I would like that if I scroll down the list, if the list is not on the top, the list is scrolled, otherwise the bottomsheet can be closed.

How can I fix this?

I have design the page like this:

- MapFragment

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.viability2.ViabilityFragment2">

    ...

     <fragment
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"        
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:layout="@android:layout/simple_gallery_item" />

     ...

     <include layout="@layout/fragment_viability_bottom_sheet_v2" />

     ...
```

- fragment_viability_bottom_sheet_v2

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/viabilityEventBottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/ftx_info_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">        
 
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            ....

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viabilityViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buttonGroup" />

       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</merge>
```

Then on the class of MapFragment I load 2 fragments on the adapter of the `ViewPager2` (let's call them X and Y). Those fragment are very simple, just a `RecyclerView` inside a `LinearLayout` with some `AppCompatTextView`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve like this

```
        binding.eventList.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        adapter = viabilityEventAdapter
        addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

                var bottomSheet = recyclerView.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent as NestedScrollView
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).apply {
                    if ((layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                        // first item of the list is visible
                        isDraggable = true
                    } else {
                        isDraggable = false
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```